# Print a scene so it exctly fits letter paper size

Tags: java, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I'm trying to print using java and building a scene with Scene Builder.

When I print, the Scene is either too small or too big and it cuts some part of the context cause it won't fit.

How can I set my Scene to print a context that EXACTLY fits a letter paper size?

Is there a way to code or set this?

I print something like this

[image: width 400 height 600]

and this

[image: width 850 height 1100]

but I want something like this

[image: desired outcome]

**UPDATE**

I am printing using page setup so I'm setting letter size there.

But still I have no idea to fit my scene perfectly or even just to center it.

**UPDATE**

I achieved my desired size through trial and error which is 600x788 scene size.

Is there a way to achieve that systematically, like fit to paper setting or something?

Comment: Can you provide some code? What did you try?

Comment: I tried changing height and with in scene builder.

Comment: I'm still searching. I don't think setting height and with is the answer. I'm thinking of set to fit or like "VGrow always" kind of code. But I haven't found it yet..